On the definition of linearly disjoint extensions
Let $E$, $F$ be two subfield of a field $\Omega$ and assume that $E$ and $F$ has a common subfield $k$.
On Wikipedia (as well as Stacks Project), $E$ and $F$ are called linearly disjoint over $k$, if the natural map
$$\theta\colon E\otimes_{k}F\longrightarrow EF,\ \sum_i e_i\otimes f_i\longmapsto \sum_i e_if_i$$
is injective. Here $EF$ means the composition of $E$ and $F$ in $\Omega$.
However, in some other textbooks (such as Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory, Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra), the linearly disjointness of $E$ and $F$ furtherly requires the above map $\theta$ to be an isomorphism.
Are these two variants of definition equivalent? I don't see why (or if) the surjectivity of $\theta$ holds naturally.

@QiaochuYuan My definition of $EF$ is the intersection of all subfields of $\Omega$ containing both $E$ and $F$.

The map is not surjective when the field extensions are not algebraic. (Also, answers should not be posted as comments.) @QiaochuYuan

Related question on mathoverflow

(I will probably write an answer later.)
